# Starting Server node on a cluster through Service and trying loadcache

Tags: ignite

I debugged the code and found all parameters being set appropriately and even in the console we can see that the server in remote node has started and the cache has been initialized.

All the requried parameters are passed through db

On trying to assert on the cache wihtout lazyload(hotloading it from the persistent store) the error log that i get is ,
I am not able to understand what s going wrong in the cluster so have only attached the code that does the job of starting the servers.
InitializeCache internally calls loadcache after all the keyfileds,jdbctypes are set..

```
class{
      private void startNodes() {

        logger.info("Starting Ignite Nodes");

        IgniteCluster igniteCluster = rocCachemanager.getCluster();

        // HashMaps for holding host and default configurations
        HashMap<String, Object> defaults = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, Object> hmHosts;

        // get Ignite configuration from DB
        List<IgniteConfigPojo> list = igniteConfigImpl.getIgniteConfigList();

        IgniteConfigPojo configPojo = list.get(0);
        List<IgniteNodeMapPojo> listNodeMap = configPojo.getIgniteNodeMap();

        // Collection of Host configuration
        Collection<Map<String, Object>> hosts = new ArrayList<>();

        // Prepare the map with all the ignite server host information
        prepareHostList(listNodeMap, hosts);
        // Actual start of remote nodes via ssh call
        try {
          if (listNodeMap.size() != igniteCluster.forServers().nodes().size()) {
            Collection<ClusterStartNodeResult> result = igniteCluster.startNodes(hosts, defaults, false, 10000, 1);
            for (ClusterStartNodeResult res : result) {
              if (!res.isSuccess()) {
                throw new ROCCacheException(res.getError());
              } else {
                logger.info("Ignite server start successfully triggered on machine " + res.getHostName());
              }

            }
          }
          int waitTime = 0;
          while (listNodeMap.size() != igniteCluster.forServers().nodes().size()) {
            if (waitTime >= MAX_TIME_FOR_SERVER_START) {
              int serverNodes = igniteCluster.forServers().nodes().size();
              throw new ROCCacheException("All the Server nodes have not joined the Ignite Cluster, Expected servers :"
                  + listNodeMap.size() + " , actual :" + serverNodes);
            }

            synchronized (this) {

              wait(2000);
            }

            waitTime += 2000;


          }
          logger.info("Successfully started all the ignite servers");

        } catch (IgniteException e) {
          throw new ROCCacheException("Error while starting the Ignite Servers", e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          throw new ROCCacheException("Error while starting the Ignite Servers,Received Interrupt signal", e);
        }

      } 

         @Override
  public void onLeaderStart() {
    startNodes();
    initializeBookeeperCache();
    initializeCaches();
  }
}
```

```
    @Test
  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
  public void startNodeTest() {

    try {
      roccacheservice.onLeaderStart();
      Collection<ClusterNode> colClusterClientNodes = rocCacheManager.getCluster().forClients().nodes();
      for (ClusterNode clientNode : colClusterClientNodes) {
        assertEquals(clientNode.addresses().contains("10.113.56.110"), true);
      }
      Collection<ClusterNode> colClusterServerNodes = rocCacheManager.getCluster().forServers().nodes();
      for (ClusterNode serverNode : colClusterServerNodes) {
        assertEquals(serverNode.addresses().contains("10.113.56.231"), true);
        System.out.println(serverNode.metrics());
```

}
****************************works fine till here****************************

```
        ROCCacheConfiguration<Long, PersonPojo> new4 = new ROCCacheConfiguration<>();
        new4.setName("Person");
        ROCCache<Long, PersonPojo> orgCache4 = rocCacheManager.createCache(new4);
        assertEquals(orgCache4.get(1L).getName(), "Abhishek");
        assertEquals(orgCache4.get(1L).getAge(), 25);



    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/abhisheks/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.19/slf4j-simple-1.7.19.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/abhisheks/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.10/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
[main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
[main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Could not instantiate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener]. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class: [org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestAttributes]
[main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@5383967b, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@2ac273d3, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@71423665, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@20398b7c, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@6fc6f14e]
[main] INFO org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@d44fc21: startup date [Tue Apr 19 15:32:01 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[main] WARN org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer - @Bean method IgniteStoreConfig.getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
[main] INFO org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer - Loading properties file from class path resource [ignitePersistentStore.properties]
[main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
[main] INFO org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
[main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'ben'
HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: ben
    ...]
HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.7.Final}
HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
HHH000457: Joined inheritance hierarchy [com.subex.roc.schema.md.TraitValue] defined explicit @DiscriminatorColumn.  Legacy Hibernate behavior was to ignore the @DiscriminatorColumn.  However, as part of issue HHH-6911 we now apply the explicit @DiscriminatorColumn.  If you would prefer the legacy behavior, enable the `hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined` setting (hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined=true)
HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_Field
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_Field
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_Model
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_Model
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_Trait
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_Trait
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_TraitGroup
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_TraitGroup
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_TraitMultiValue
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_TraitMultiValue
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_TraitSingleValue
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_TraitSingleValue
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_TraitValueBase
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_TraitValueBase
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_TraitValueStore
HHH000262: Table not found: SREG_TraitValueStore
HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: select igniteconf0_.icf_id as icf_id1_0_, igniteconf0_.enable_peerclassload as enable_p2_0_, igniteconf0_.grid_name as grid_nam3_0_, igniteconf0_.join_timeout as join_tim4_0_ from ignite_config igniteconf0_
Hibernate: select ignitenode0_.icf_id as icf_id3_1_0_, ignitenode0_.inm_id as inm_id1_1_0_, ignitenode0_.inm_id as inm_id1_1_1_, ignitenode0_.icf_id as icf_id3_1_1_, ignitenode0_.nod_id as nod_id4_1_1_, ignitenode0_.port_range as port_ran2_1_1_, rocnodepoj1_.nod_id as nod_id1_4_2_, rocnodepoj1_.nod_address as nod_addr2_4_2_, rocnodedea2_.rnd_id as rnd_id1_3_3_, rocnodedea2_.nod_id as nod_id2_3_3_, rocnodedea2_.rnd_ignite_home as rnd_igni3_3_3_, rocnodedea2_.rnd_numberof_nodes as rnd_numb4_3_3_, rocnodedea2_.rnd_password as rnd_pass5_3_3_, rocnodedea2_.rnd_ssh_port as rnd_ssh_6_3_3_, rocnodedea2_.rnd_user_name as rnd_user7_3_3_ from ignite_node_map ignitenode0_ left outer join roc_nodes rocnodepoj1_ on ignitenode0_.nod_id=rocnodepoj1_.nod_id left outer join roc_node_detail rocnodedea2_ on rocnodepoj1_.nod_id=rocnodedea2_.rnd_id where ignitenode0_.icf_id=?
[main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/home/abhisheks/Desktop/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0.final-bin/conf/spring_igniteConfig.xml]
[main] INFO org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/home/abhisheks/Desktop/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0.final-bin/conf/ignite_Config.xml]
[main] INFO org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@5d8ab698: startup date [Tue Apr 19 15:32:04 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[main] INFO org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource - Loaded JDBC driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver


>>>    __________  ________________  
>>>   /  _/ ___/ |/ /  _/_  __/ __/  
>>>  _/ // (7 7    // /  / / / _/    
>>> /___/\___/_/|_/___/ /_/ /___/   
>>> 
>>> ver. 1.5.0-final#20151229-sha1:f1f8cda2
>>> 2015 Copyright(C) Apache Software Foundation
>>> 
>>> Ignite documentation: http://ignite.apache.org

Config URL: file:/home/abhisheks/Desktop/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0.final-bin/conf/spring_igniteConfig.xml
Daemon mode: off
OS: Linux 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 amd64
OS user: abhisheks
Language runtime: Java Platform API Specification ver. 1.8
VM information: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_66-b17 Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.66-b17
VM total memory: 1.7GB
Remote Management [restart: off, REST: on, JMX (remote: off)]
IGNITE_HOME=/home/abhisheks/Desktop/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0.final-bin
VM arguments: [-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8]
Configured caches ['ignite-marshaller-sys-cache', 'ignite-sys-cache', 'ignite-atomics-sys-cache']
3-rd party licenses can be found at: /home/abhisheks/Desktop/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0.final-bin/libs/licenses
Initial heap size is 122MB (should be no less than 512MB, use -Xms512m -Xmx512m).
Non-loopback local IPs: 10.113.56.110, 192.168.122.1, fe80:0:0:0:c634:6bff:fe4f:784d%eth1
Enabled local MACs: 5254004ABB26, C4346B4F784D
Configured plugins:
  ^-- None

IPC shared memory server endpoint started [port=48100, tokDir=/home/abhisheks/Desktop/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0.final-bin/work/ipc/shmem/8f12688b-fef6-4981-a5f4-aa6781438930-23547]
Successfully bound shared memory communication to TCP port [port=48100, locHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0]
Successfully bound to TCP port [port=47100, locHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0]
Checkpoints are disabled (to enable configure any GridCheckpointSpi implementation)
Collision resolution is disabled (all jobs will be activated upon arrival).
Swap space is disabled. To enable use FileSwapSpaceSpi.
Security status [authentication=off, tls/ssl=off]
Command protocol successfully started [name=TCP binary, host=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0, port=11211]
Successfully bound to TCP port [port=47500, localHost=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0]
Started cache [name=ignite-sys-cache, mode=REPLICATED]
Started cache [name=ignite-atomics-sys-cache, mode=PARTITIONED]
Started cache [name=ignite-marshaller-sys-cache, mode=REPLICATED]
Performance suggestions for grid 'subexIgnite' (fix if possible)
To disable, set -DIGNITE_PERFORMANCE_SUGGESTIONS_DISABLED=true
  ^-- Disable grid events (remove 'includeEventTypes' from configuration)
  ^-- Enable client mode for TcpDiscoverySpi (set TcpDiscoverySpi.forceServerMode to false)

To start Console Management & Monitoring run ignitevisorcmd.{sh|bat}



>>> +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Ignite ver. 1.5.0-final#20151229-sha1:f1f8cda2f3f62231f42a59951bf34c39577c1bec
>>> +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> OS name: Linux 2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64 amd64
>>> CPU(s): 8
>>> Heap: 1.7GB
>>> VM name: 23547@abhisheks
>>> Grid name: subexIgnite
>>> Local node [ID=8F12688B-FEF6-4981-A5F4-AA6781438930, order=1, clientMode=true]
>>> Local node addresses: [192.168.122.1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, abhisheks/10.113.56.110, /127.0.0.1, /192.168.122.1]
>>> Local ports: TCP:11211 TCP:47100 TCP:47500 TCP:48100 

Topology snapshot [ver=1, servers=0, clients=1, CPUs=8, heap=1.7GB]
[main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext - Began transaction (1) for test context [DefaultTestContext@2478b629 testClass = StartServiceTest, testInstance = com.subex.roc.cache.startserviceintegration.StartServiceTest@39023dbf, testMethod = startNodeTest@StartServiceTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@2c2c3947 testClass = StartServiceTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.subex.roc.cache.IgniteJPAConfiguration, class com.subex.roc.cache.IgniteEnvConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]; transaction manager [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager@1a2ac487]; rollback [true]
[main] INFO com.subex.roc.cache.ROCCacheService - Starting Ignite Nodes
Hibernate: select igniteconf0_.icf_id as icf_id1_0_, igniteconf0_.enable_peerclassload as enable_p2_0_, igniteconf0_.grid_name as grid_nam3_0_, igniteconf0_.join_timeout as join_tim4_0_ from ignite_config igniteconf0_
Hibernate: select ignitenode0_.icf_id as icf_id3_1_0_, ignitenode0_.inm_id as inm_id1_1_0_, ignitenode0_.inm_id as inm_id1_1_1_, ignitenode0_.icf_id as icf_id3_1_1_, ignitenode0_.nod_id as nod_id4_1_1_, ignitenode0_.port_range as port_ran2_1_1_, rocnodepoj1_.nod_id as nod_id1_4_2_, rocnodepoj1_.nod_address as nod_addr2_4_2_, rocnodedea2_.rnd_id as rnd_id1_3_3_, rocnodedea2_.nod_id as nod_id2_3_3_, rocnodedea2_.rnd_ignite_home as rnd_igni3_3_3_, rocnodedea2_.rnd_numberof_nodes as rnd_numb4_3_3_, rocnodedea2_.rnd_password as rnd_pass5_3_3_, rocnodedea2_.rnd_ssh_port as rnd_ssh_6_3_3_, rocnodedea2_.rnd_user_name as rnd_user7_3_3_ from ignite_node_map ignitenode0_ left outer join roc_nodes rocnodepoj1_ on ignitenode0_.nod_id=rocnodepoj1_.nod_id left outer join roc_node_detail rocnodedea2_ on rocnodepoj1_.nod_id=rocnodedea2_.rnd_id where ignitenode0_.icf_id=?
Starting remote node with SSH command: nohup "/home/benakaraj/Downloads/apache-ignite-fabric-1.5.0.final-bin/bin/ignite.sh" -v "conf/spring_igniteConfig.xml" -J-DIGNITE_SSH_HOST="10.113.56.231" -J-DIGNITE_SSH_USER_NAME="root" > ignite-startNodes/04-19-2016--15-32-05-521bc7ca.log 2>& 1 &
[main] INFO com.subex.roc.cache.ROCCacheService - Ignite server start successfully triggered on machine 10.113.56.231
Your version is up to date.
Local java version is different from remote [loc=8, rmt=7]
Added new node to topology: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=e93bc2fa-8a37-4a50-9a22-071abece643f, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1, 10.113.56.231, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.122.1], sockAddrs=[/192.168.122.1:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:47500, /10.113.56.231:47500, /10.113.56.231:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, /192.168.122.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=2, intOrder=2, lastExchangeTime=1461060127285, loc=false, ver=1.5.0#20151229-sha1:f1f8cda2, isClient=false]
Topology snapshot [ver=2, servers=1, clients=1, CPUs=16, heap=2.7GB]
[main] INFO com.subex.roc.cache.ROCCacheService - Successfully started all the ignite servers
Started cache [name=bookeeperCache, mode=PARTITIONED]
Hibernate: select roccacheco0_.rcc_id as rcc_id1_2_, roccacheco0_.automicity_mode as automici2_2_, roccacheco0_.backup_count as backup_c3_2_, roccacheco0_.cache_mode as cache_mo4_2_, roccacheco0_.cache_writeorder_mode as cache_wr5_2_, roccacheco0_.eviction_policy as eviction6_2_, roccacheco0_.filterClass as filterCl7_2_, roccacheco0_.is_lazy_load as is_lazy_8_2_, roccacheco0_.is_near_cache as is_near_9_2_, roccacheco0_.is_read_through as is_read10_2_, roccacheco0_.is_write_behind as is_writ11_2_, roccacheco0_.is_write_through as is_writ12_2_, roccacheco0_.key_class as key_cla13_2_, roccacheco0_.max_cache_entries as max_cac14_2_, roccacheco0_.rcc_cache_name as rcc_cac15_2_, roccacheco0_.rcc_table_name as rcc_tab16_2_, roccacheco0_.schema_version as schema_17_2_, roccacheco0_.value_class as value_c18_2_, roccacheco0_.writebehind_batch_size as writebe19_2_, roccacheco0_.writebehind_flush_freq as writebe20_2_, roccacheco0_.writebehind_flush_size as writebe21_2_ from roc_cache_config roccacheco0_
Hibernate: select model0_.id as id1_6_, model0_.description as descript2_6_, model0_.name as name3_6_, model0_.version as version4_6_ from SREG_Model model0_ where model0_.name=? and model0_.version=?
Hibernate: select fields0_.model_id as model_id5_5_0_, fields0_.id as id1_5_0_, fields0_.id as id1_5_1_, fields0_.name as name2_5_1_, fields0_.position as position3_5_1_, fields0_.type as type4_5_1_ from SREG_Field fields0_ where fields0_.model_id=?
Hibernate: select traitgroup0_.field_id as field_id3_8_0_, traitgroup0_.id as id1_8_0_, traitgroup0_.id as id1_8_1_, traitgroup0_.name as name2_8_1_ from SREG_TraitGroup traitgroup0_ where traitgroup0_.field_id=?
Hibernate: select traitgroup0_.field_id as field_id3_8_0_, traitgroup0_.id as id1_8_0_, traitgroup0_.id as id1_8_1_, traitgroup0_.name as name2_8_1_ from SREG_TraitGroup traitgroup0_ where traitgroup0_.field_id=?
Hibernate: select traitgroup0_.field_id as field_id3_8_0_, traitgroup0_.id as id1_8_0_, traitgroup0_.id as id1_8_1_, traitgroup0_.name as name2_8_1_ from SREG_TraitGroup traitgroup0_ where traitgroup0_.field_id=?
Hibernate: select traitgroup0_.model_id as model_id4_8_0_, traitgroup0_.id as id1_8_0_, traitgroup0_.id as id1_8_1_, traitgroup0_.name as name2_8_1_ from SREG_TraitGroup traitgroup0_ where traitgroup0_.model_id=?
Hibernate: select traits0_.group_id as group_id5_7_0_, traits0_.id as id1_7_0_, traits0_.id as id1_7_1_, traits0_.data_type as data_typ2_7_1_, traits0_.name as name3_7_1_, traits0_.trait_id as trait_id4_7_1_, traitvalue1_.id as id2_11_2_, traitvalue1_2_.value as value1_10_2_, traitvalue1_.trait_type as trait_ty1_11_2_ from SREG_Trait traits0_ left outer join SREG_TraitValueBase traitvalue1_ on traits0_.trait_id=traitvalue1_.id left outer join SREG_TraitMultiValue traitvalue1_1_ on traitvalue1_.id=traitvalue1_1_.id left outer join SREG_TraitSingleValue traitvalue1_2_ on traitvalue1_.id=traitvalue1_2_.id where traits0_.group_id=?
Started cache [name=Person, mode=REPLICATED]
Failed to obtain remote job result policy for result from ComputeTask.result(..) method (will fail the whole task): GridJobResultImpl [job=C2 [], sib=GridJobSiblingImpl [sesId=e4f38fd2451-8f12688b-fef6-4981-a5f4-aa6781438930, jobId=15f38fd2451-e93bc2fa-8a37-4a50-9a22-071abece643f, nodeId=e93bc2fa-8a37-4a50-9a22-071abece643f, isJobDone=false], jobCtx=GridJobContextImpl [jobId=15f38fd2451-e93bc2fa-8a37-4a50-9a22-071abece643f, timeoutObj=null, attrs={}], node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=e93bc2fa-8a37-4a50-9a22-071abece643f, addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1, 10.113.56.231, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.122.1], sockAddrs=[/192.168.122.1:47500, /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%1:47500, /10.113.56.231:47500, /10.113.56.231:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500, /192.168.122.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=2, intOrder=2, lastExchangeTime=1461060127285, loc=false, ver=1.5.0#20151229-sha1:f1f8cda2, isClient=false], ex=class o.a.i.IgniteException: null, hasRes=true, isCancelled=false, isOccupied=true]
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Remote job threw user exception (override or implement ComputeTask.result(..) method if you would like to have automatic failover for this exception).
    at org.apache.ignite.compute.ComputeTaskAdapter.result(ComputeTaskAdapter.java:101)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$3.apply(GridTaskWorker.java:909)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$3.apply(GridTaskWorker.java:902)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6429)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.result(GridTaskWorker.java:902)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.onResponse(GridTaskWorker.java:798)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.processJobExecuteResponse(GridTaskProcessor.java:995)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$JobMessageListener.onMessage(GridTaskProcessor.java:1219)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:821)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1600(GridIoManager.java:103)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$5.run(GridIoManager.java:784)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: null
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2.execute(GridClosureProcessor.java:1792)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$2.call(GridJobWorker.java:509)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6397)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:503)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:456)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1166)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:1770)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:821)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1600(GridIoManager.java:103)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$5.run(GridIoManager.java:784)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheClosure.call(GridCacheAdapter.java:5769)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheClosure.call(GridCacheAdapter.java:5716)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2.execute(GridClosureProcessor.java:1789)
    ... 13 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheClosure.call(GridCacheAdapter.java:5769)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheClosure.call(GridCacheAdapter.java:5716)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2.execute(GridClosureProcessor.java:1789)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$2.call(GridJobWorker.java:509)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6397)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:503)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:456)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1166)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:1770)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:821)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$1600(GridIoManager.java:103)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$5.run(GridIoManager.java:784)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionContext - Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@2478b629 testClass = StartServiceTest, testInstance = com.subex.roc.cache.startserviceintegration.StartServiceTest@39023dbf, testMethod = startNodeTest@StartServiceTest, testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@2c2c3947 testClass = StartServiceTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.subex.roc.cache.IgniteJPAConfiguration, class com.subex.roc.cache.IgniteEnvConfiguration}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
Invoking shutdown hook...
[Thread-3] INFO org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@d44fc21: startup date [Tue Apr 19 15:32:01 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Command protocol successfully stopped: TCP binary
Stopped cache: ignite-marshaller-sys-cache
Stopped cache: ignite-sys-cache
Stopped cache: ignite-atomics-sys-cache
Stopped cache: bookeeperCache
Stopped cache: Person


>>> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Ignite ver. 1.5.0-final#20151229-sha1:f1f8cda2f3f62231f42a59951bf34c39577c1bec stopped OK
>>> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Grid name: subexIgnite
>>> Grid uptime: 00:00:14:747


[Thread-3] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'ben'
```

Comment: The Exception occurred because the remote node was not given user priviliges to acces the DB.

Answer (score 0):

The possibility of this NPE is removed in the latest Ignite version (1.6.0). It can be downloaded here: ignite.apache.org/download.cgi#binaries